# Plotting time series object

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to plot a time series version of a matrix `mx`. I used the following code, however the x axis does not show the dates I have. It shows some numbers instead and do not really trace the problem.

```
mx_ts<-ts(mx)
plot(mx_ts, type="l")
```

reproducible example `mx` is as follow:

```
structure(c("0.233632449583826", "0.252105485477729", "0.591295809149662", 
"0.0901324567177099", "-0.0423290120373304", "0.0363874105632916", 
"-0.136952003053153", "0.451355935617868", "-0.291897852322839", 
"0.287789031880016", "-2.1", "-1.4", "-2.6", "1.9", "-0.7", "1.4", 
"-0.6", "-1.3", "-1.4", "0"), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1985-01", "1985-02", "1985-03", "1985-04", "1985-05", 
    "1985-06", "1985-07", "1985-08", "1985-09", "1985-10"), c("return", 
    "ukcc")))
```

Comment: Note that `df` is a matrix and not a data frame as the name might suggest. Also it contains character strings, not numbers.  There may be a problem in how it was constructed in the first place.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I have changed all `df` to be `mx`(did also that in the answers) not to make any confusion. The character string is the `date` column and this makes a problem in every subsequent analysis. Tried to change it with `as.Date` but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of other options:

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)

# Convert to time series object with dates by month
mx.ts = ts(mx, start=as.yearmon(rownames(mx)[1]), frequency=12)

# Plot with fractional years on x-axis
plot(mx.ts)
```

[image]

```
# Plot with month-year on x-axis
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(as.xts(mx.ts[,"return"]), major.format="%b-%Y", cex.axis=0.7, main="Return")
plot(as.xts(mx.ts[,"ukcc"]), major.format="%b-%Y", cex.axis=0.7, main="ukcc")
```

[image]

And there's always the `ggplot2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

mx2 = cbind(Date=rownames(mx), mx)
names(mx2)=c("Date","Return","ukcc")

# Melt data into "long" format
mx2.m = melt(mx2, id.var="Date")

ggplot(mx2.m, aes(Date, value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Quite comprehensive answer. One thing; I got the following error when running the last line of the `ggplot` answer. Error in `layout_base(data, rows, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`

Comment: That means you used a variable name in `facet_grid` that is not found in the data frame your plotting. If you print out `df2.m` in your console, you'll see that melting `df2` created a new column called `variable` which contains the values `Return` and `ukcc`. You need a column like that in your own data for facetting. `melt` calls it `variable` by default, but you can set it to whatever you like.

Comment: I am just using the same above example so nothing changed.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without seeing the structure of your data frame and the exact plotting code you ran. As long as there's a column called `variable` in your data frame, you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: I have different names; the `Date` column called `Var1`, `group` called `Var2` and the values called `value`. Quite surprising as you set the `id.var` to be `"Date"`. I changed them in the code and it works, however, it adds another plot for the `Date` group along with`ukcc` and `Return`.

Answer (score 2):

The `zoo` class might be preferable in this case:

```
library(zoo)
##
Dates <- as.Date(paste0(row.names(mx),"-01"))
mx_zoo <- zoo(apply(mx,2,as.numeric),Dates)
##
> plot(mx_zoo)
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Here's a quick way to get year information on the x-axis, using @Henrik's suggestion:

```
mx_zoo2 <- zoo(apply(mx,2,as.numeric),
               as.yearmon(Dates))
> plot(mx_zoo2)
```

[image]

You can adjust the axis labels if you play around with `axis` a bit, but to be honest I think @eipi10's answer covers this really well, so I would recommend taking his approach instead.

Comment: That works fine. May I know what does `"-01"` mean? also, how can I get years on x axis instead of months?

Comment: You may also use `order.by = as.yearmon(rownames(df))`

Comment: The "-01" adds the day of the month to each date so that `as.Date` will work properly.

Comment: Once you have it as a zoo object you could also plot it in ggplot2 like this:  `library(ggplot2); autoplot(df_zoo)` or `autoplot(df_zoo, facet = NULL)`  assuming `Date` class index.  If the index is of class `yearmon` then `library(scales); autoplot(df_zoo) + scale_x_yearmon()` .